# IE10/IE11 does not display unicode characters inside of SVG

Tags: internet-explorer, d3.js, svg, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

I'm using D3.js for displaying unicode character inside of SVG as seen below.

```
g.append("text")
        .html("&#10148;");
```

This works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome, but displays nothing in IE10/11.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using .text instead of .html. I.e.

```
g.append("text")
        .text("&#10148;");
```

I don't think IE supports .html for SVG content.